# Duplicate output from jq when processing JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON data structure the looks like this"

```
{
    "cells": [
     {
      "source": [
       "# Get the files in a directory \n",
       "ls -l \n"
      ]
     },
     {
      "source": [
        "# Get the working directory \n",
        "pwd \n"
      ]
     },
     {
      "source": [
       "# Get the network config \n",
       "ipconfig \n"
      ]
     }
    ],
    "metadata": {
     "kernelspec": {
      "display_name": "Bash",
      "language": "bash",
      "name": "bash"
     }
    }
}
```

I want to create a new structure from it that looks like this:

```
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the files in a directory \n",
    "ls -l \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the files in a directory \n"
}
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the files in a directory \n",
    "ls -l \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the working directory \n"
}
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the files in a directory \n",
    "ls -l \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the network config \n"
}
```

My jq command looks like this:

```
cat test.json | jq '{source: .cells[].source, title: .cells[].source[0] }'
```

However I'm getting duplicate records in the output. I know it has something to do with the way that jq is processing the input data. Is there a way handle this scenario ?

Comment: With `.cells[]` repeated, you are iterating multiple times over the same array, producing its cartesian product. Factor out the iteration, and combine your object from there: `jq '.cells[] | {source, title: .source[0]}' test.json`

Comment: Thank you - I actually almost had this, except I had a quote in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, it looks like you want:

```
.cells[] | .title = .source[0]
```

On the other hand, the sample input shown in the Q does not seem to match up with the sample output.

Or, in accordance with your comment:

```
{commands: [.cells[] | .title = .source[0]]}
```

Comment: One further thing that's bugging me and I can't work out. How can I get the data formatted as an array of objects. e.g {commands: [ {source, title}, ... ]

Comment: OK thanks that did it. That's exactly what I wanted. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate your `cells` array only once. You have at least 3 options that will all produce the same output:

##### Assignment operator [`=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Plainassignment:=)

See [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668975/112968)

```
.cells[] | .title = .source[0]
```

It will assign the first item in `.source` to the (new) property `.title` of each cell

##### Merging objects [`+`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Addition:+)

Construct a new object by merging in a new object with a single property into the existing cell:

```
.cells[] = . + {title: .source[0]}
```

This is useful if you want to add several new properties

##### Reconstructing result objects from scratch [`{}`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D)

Since your objects only contains a single property, you can reconstruct the result object from scratch, listing all old and new properties:

```
.cells[] | {source, title: .source[0]}
```

Useful if the result structure does not resemble the input structure or uses only a few properties of the input.

---

The output for all 3 programs is:

```json
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the files in a directory \n",
    "ls -l \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the files in a directory \n"
}
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the working directory \n",
    "pwd \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the working directory \n"
}
{
  "source": [
    "# Get the network config \n",
    "ipconfig \n"
  ],
  "title": "# Get the network config \n"
}
```